# Distribution List in Notification Task in IICS

Tags: email, notifications, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

Can we add distribution lists in notification task in IICS, I tried the below and it's not sending any emails to the DL's.

Could you please suggest if there's any alternative for the same.

[image]

Note :  It's working for Individual emails.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Distribution lists can be added to notification tasks, but only if an admin creates them at server side. if dl is created by developer those will not work